# Convert Flux<Map<K, V>> into List<V>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm wondering how in spring reactor to convert a `Flux<Map<K, V>` into a `List<V>`.

Comment: Flux<Map<String, Object> => List<Object> . I don't care about key of the map

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a Flux instance you can do:

```
List<Object> myList = flux.collectSortedList().block();
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Flux<Map<K, V>>` can emit any number of maps (0..infinity values).

```
final List<V> values = flux
    .flatMapIterable(Map::values) // extract a concatenated list of all values
                                  // it transforms List<Collection<V>> into Collection<V>
                                  // but keeps it wrapped in a Flux instance
    .collectList() // transforms Flux<T> into Mono<List<T>>
    .block(); // blocks indefinitely, until the value is available and returns the value
```